# How do I optimize an array heavy code in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

Sorry, this is probably a very noob question, but I'm converting some code I've been modeling with from MATLAB to Python both to help me learn Python and to see if it could run it any faster. In MATLAB, this code takes about 1 second to run, but in Python, it takes about 1 minute. Is there some way to speed it up, or is this not a good application of Python?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 7e5 #number of  time steps
dt = 1e-6 #Time step, in seconds
tf = dt*N #Final time, seconds. 
trange = np.linspace(0,tf,int(N+1)) #time range

dx = L/M #spatial step size in thermoelectric, meters

#Define dimensionless fourier number in thermoelectric
Fo = dt*(k/c)/(dx**2)

#temperature profile in thermoelectric as a function of space and time
T = np.zeros((M+1,2))
#Allocate initial condition
T[:,0] = Ti
#Set boundary condition at x=L
T[M,:] = T2

#temperature v time profile of coldside of thermoelectric
coldTemp = np.zeros(len(trange))
#initial coldside temp
coldTemp[0] = Ti
#setting current to optimum DC value
I = Issmax

#iterate over timesteps
for p in range(int(N)):
     
    #Use central difference forward time method to find temperature within
    #thermoelectric material.
    for n in range(M-1):       
        #calculate temp. change at next time step
        T[n+1,1] = T[n+1,0] + Fo*(T[n+2,0]-2*T[n+1,0]+T[n,0]) + dt*((I)**2*rho/(c*d**2*w**2))
    
    #Apply energy balance to the metal (assumed isothermal) and use the
    #fact that the metal temp is equal to the thermoelectric temp
    T[0,1] = T[0,0] + dt*((I)**2*rhom/(cm*lm**2*wm**2)) - (k*dt/(cm*dx*lm))*(T[0,0]-T[1,0]) - (dt*(I)*S*T[0,0]/(cm*d*w*lm))
    #Saving coldside temp
    coldTemp[p+1] = T[0,1]
    #Setting current temperature profile to be calculated one
    T[:,0] = T[:,1]

#Plotting coldside temp vs time
plt.plot(trange, coldTemp)
```

Comment: The default Python implementation (CPython) is an *interpreter* while the default one of Matlab is a JIT *compiler*. Compilers are generally much faster than interpreters, especially for your code. Generally, the way to speed up Numpy code is to *vectorize* operations (ie. work on array and prevent loops). However, in your case, you have a loop-carried dependencies so vectorizing the code is hard. The simplest and fastest solution is certainly to use a JIT like *Numba* or an AOT compiler like *Cython*.

Comment: Besides this, please avoid division by constants (compute the inverse if possible) because they are expensive. Moreover, note that if you do not use NaN values nor infinite values, neither fancy IEEE-754 tricks, then you can use fastmath compiler optimizations.

Comment: Most likely those two loops are taking the most time.  'vectorize' in `numpy` means using whole-array operations, as opposed to python level iterations.  It's like we used to use in MATLAB before they added the JIT stuff.  But "vectorizing" the inner loop may be difficult since it sets the `n+1` value based on the `n,n+1,n+2` values, essentially a sequential operation.

Comment: It might be faster if `T` was a list or two.  The `T[n+1,1] = T...` line is not doing any array calculations.  The line is a scalar.  Iterating like this on an array is slower than list iteration.

Answer (score 0):

the suggestions in comments above are good, but before **anything** else, you are violating perhaps **the #1 rule of making loops faster**:  **Don't do things inside of a loop that can be done outside.**  You are re-computing the same values billions of times, and they are "expensive" with division and exponentiation.  Consider something like this...  (Check the math, I wasn't too careful, and perhaps there is more you can do)

```
...  
# calculate the constants...
c1 = dt*((I)**2*rho/(c*d**2*w**2))
c2 = dt*((I)**2*rhom/(cm*lm**2*wm**2))
c3 = (k*dt/(cm*dx*lm))
c4 = (dt*(I)*S/(cm*d*w*lm))

#iterate over timesteps
for p in range(int(N)):
     
    #Use central difference forward time method to find temperature within
    #thermoelectric material.
    for n in range(M-1):       
        #calculate temp. change at next time step
        T[n+1,1] = T[n+1,0] + Fo*(T[n+2,0]-2*T[n+1,0]+T[n,0]) + c1
    
    #Apply energy balance to the metal (assumed isothermal) and use the
    #fact that the metal temp is equal to the thermoelectric temp
    T[0,1] = T[0,0] + c2 - c3*(T[0,0]-T[1,0]) - c4*T[0,0]
    #Saving coldside temp
    coldTemp[p+1] = T[0,1]
    #Setting current temperature profile to be calculated one
    T[:,0] = T[:,1]
```